# Get specific values from MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, find

I am trying to retrieve just the value from certain fields in MongoDB Atlas, so far I can return the field and value, but I just want to return the value.

I have a database in my local environment called Game, and a collection called Scores. In the Scores collection, there are three fields: id, title, and score. When I run the command:

```
db.Scores.find({}, {_id:0,title:0})
```

I get the expected result of:

```
[ { score: 17 }, { score: 0 } ]
```

In MongoDB Atlas I have the same DB and connect using Mongoose.

If I run the following code I also get a similar result:

```
Scores.find({}, {_id:0, title: 0}, function(err, scores) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(scores[0]);
        console.log(scores[1]);
    };
});
```

Result:

```
{ score: 17 }
{ score: 0 }
```

But what I really want is just to get the actual values. I.e. the 17, and 0?

I have looked through the documentation and can't seem to find a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it client side, or if you want to do it in query then use aggregation with `$group` operator, but it's not efficient if you have huge documents.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
db.Scores.find(
   {},
   { score: 1}
).toArray().map( x => x.score )
```

Comment: Hey there. Sorry I am new to this, and failed to mention that in my local environment your suggestion works great (although how do I then get those values from the array? I assume x.score[0] and x.score[1]?).
However when I then try to use this in my mongoose atlas DB it doesn't like it.

Comment: It depends on your client. Code above is JavaScript, i.e. mongo shell or Node. Most clients should provide method to convert cursor into an Array and perform such map.